# show custom dialog only once with onclick Button

Tags: java, android, dialog, sharedpreferences

i'm trying to show my custom dialog only once ; firstly i have a custom dialog contains one `button` **OK** when i click ok button and re open app i want to hide the custom dialog for that i tried to use `SharedPreference`

```
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
        editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("key_name", false);

/**/

 if (pref.getBoolean("key_name", true)) {
                users();
  }

private void users() {
        final Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        myDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        assert myDialog.getWindow() != null;
        myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        myDialog.setCancelable(false);
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.users_artwork_dialog);
        Button okbtn = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.okbtn);

        okbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
                @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits") SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("key_name", false);
                myDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        myDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: only add editor.commit(); https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#ReadSharedPreference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do **`editor.commit()`** or **`editor.apply()`** to save the changes to **SharedPreference** in **users()** method. That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should either **`commit()`** or **`apply()`** SharedPreference editor.

> **`void commit()`** :
>   Commit your preferences changes back from this Editor to the SharedPreferences object it is editing. This atomically performs the requested modifications, replacing whatever is currently in the SharedPreferences.
>
> **`void apply ()`**
>   Commit your preferences changes back from this Editor to the SharedPreferences object it is editing. This atomically performs the requested modifications, replacing whatever is currently in the SharedPreferences.

Check your modified code as well

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    SharedPreferences pref;

    @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
        editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("key_name", true);
        //Add commit()
        editor.commit();

/**/

        if (pref.getBoolean("key_name", false)) {
            users();
        }
    }
    private void users() {
        final Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        myDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        assert myDialog.getWindow() != null;
        myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        myDialog.setCancelable(false);
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.users_artwork_dialog);
        Button okbtn = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.okbtn);

        okbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
                @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits") SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("key_name", false);
                //Add commit()
                editor.commit();
                myDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        myDialog.show();
    }
```